# Load balancing clients correlation failed

Tags: .net, load-balancing, haproxy, identityserver4

Currently I've setup where I have HAProxy which points to:
1 identity server
and load balanced client web site on two different machines.

For all of them I am using shared certificate, and clients use open id hybrid flow.

Everything works as expected, when I have only 1 client running simultaneously.

**Whenever second client is enabled on callback (http://identityclient.local/signin-oidc) from identity server I get error:**

```
  System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Any help is much appreciated :(

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correlation failed. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler during OIDC authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124498/correlation-failed-at-microsoft-aspnetcore-authentication-remoteauthenticationh)