# Correlation failed. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler during OIDC authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, azure-application-gateway

I am hitting this with the following combination:

1. Browser incognito mode (Chrome)
2. Application is behind Azure application gateway (no repro if it isn't). Cookie based affinity is turned OFF (default); if turned ON, seems to make repro happen more often.

Code is rather plain vanilla OIDC authN + cookies.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAd(options => {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        })
        .AddCookie(p => p.SlidingExpiration = true);
```

I am forwarding the X-Forwarded-Proto header to the auth middleware as recommended so the redirect_uri uses the correct protocol scheme.

**HANDLING IN CODE**

I tried to handle the **OnRemoteFailure()** event, and redirect to "/Home/AuthRedirect" which is an anon page that waits for 20 secs, and then redirects to the "/" (home page). It seems to work sometimes, but not always. I am out of ideas.

**WORKAROUND**

1. Users can go to the homepage again and hit F5 until this works. It seems that each F5 gets them moving a step ahead and once the OpenID cookies are populated, everything else (I have more auth after openid finishes, via adal.js for AJAX use).
2. Bypass the application gateway and use the direct service fabric cluster DNS name (not acceptable as it is http).

**DETAILS**

```
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the Expires/MaxAge time in Chrome debugger always showing 1969-12-31. That means my cookies are session cookies, but I am having trouble making them persistent.

Comment: I made them persistent. No impact on this problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have same problem, if your environment is web farm, you should use DataProtection to share key.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What does "use DataProtection to share key" mean in this context?

Comment: Actually I get it now. Once I added the DataProtection middleware, the issue is no longer repro. Here's my explanation: the GET call to AD happened from a Node that is different from the node that processed the POST /signin-oidc request; because the encryption/decryption keys for the cookies (nonce, I believe) are DIFFERENT between the nodes (due to lack of the DataProtection middleware), decryption fails, and hence "Correlation Failed" error. I used .AddDataProtection() and used a blob store container to host the keys xml. No more repro of the "Correlation failed" error.

Comment: How do you add the DataProtection middleware?

Comment: @BlackFox in StartUp.cs file --> ConfigureServices method --> type this in: "services.AddDataProtection();"

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar Correlation error in Chrome but not Safari... turns out that when SameSite.None is being used you must run your custom site (even localhost) using https.  That solved all my correlation woes.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but my issue was due to my understanding of auth workflow, which was wrong.
There are two callback URLs that are important, and I thought they serve the same purpose. I was so wrong.

This is defined in Startup.cs

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options =>
            {
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-auth0");
```

It tells the authorisation middleware in your app, on which URL it should listen, once auth provider gets back after successful authentication.
Then the middleware itself will redirect the application to the callback URL defined in your Login action (sample code is below).

After that (two days of struggle), everything started working.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Login()
    {
        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Auth0", new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/my-callback-page" });
    }
}
```

Comment: any idea what the callback url does? I am running into a similar issue and confused by it. It seems like regardless of what I set the redirect url to after challenge, the middleware redirects to whatever page the user landed on (e.g. if they bookmark the profile page)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I was defining multiple external endpoints for Authorization.
In my case I had defined Callback Paths that were being used by multiple clients. 
Once I defined unique Callback Paths the problem was solved: 
example:

```
  options.Authority = …..";
.
.
  options.CallbackPath = "/signin-idsrv2"; // I already had /sign-in-idsrv
```

Similarly, make sure the `SignedOutCallbackPaths` are unique.
Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was not the case in your example, but I had an issue with same error message just today after a change to Winter Time - my clock was for some reason not automatically synchronized and system time was still one hour ahead - after synchronizing with remote Time server, everything started to work again. I hope someone finds this helpful.